# \rm \bf command not working in htlatex

Tags: htlatex

When i have using `\rm` and `\bf` command in LaTeX file, `htlatex` does not converted. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

test $AA {\rm asdffda}_BB$ and $\it{italic}_a$ and $\bf{boldtext}_a$

$${\rm textrm}_a and {\it italic}_a and {\bf boldtext}_a$$

\end{document}
```

`htlatex filename.tex "test.cfg,mathltx"`

How do get this

Comment: `\rm`, `\it`, `\bf` -- as well as `\tt`, `\sc`, `\sl`, and `\sf` -- are all considered deprecated in LaTeX documents. Thus, write `$AA \mathrm{asdffda}_{BB}$`,  `$\mathit{italic}_a$`, and `$\mathbf{boldtext}_a$`.

Comment: ...ss well as `$$...$$` is deprecated too, use `\[...\]` instead

Comment: @Balaji; I think I've a solution for the bibliography problem you posted  (then deleted) on May, 19th (jmb bib style). Is there a place where I could post it?